# Securing RestAPI using Oauth in java

Tags: java, api, web-services, oauth-2.0, jax-rs

I have created some `APIs` using `JAX-RS jersey`. I have been given task to secure them using `Oauth 2.0`. In google I found many articles in which they explain how can I access google API, facebook API etc. they told me how to access already created APIs

But my question is how can I make my `API` secure using `Oauth` in `java` so that when another `applcation` want to access, it needs to provide `authorization` and `authentication` token etc.

Can anybody help me with the `code` in `java`. you can suggest some even paid tutorial of udemy coursera if you know. I will opt for them. I am not using any framework like Spring or Springboot.

Answer (score 0):

I would advies checking out the following page:
 https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt

It makes use of keycloack for authorization server and spring for configuring the resource server.